# Why does the current_user is always user_id = 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I cannot figure out why the current_user is always set to user_id = 1.

When it edits the data, it sets user_id appropriately but when it is creating a new record, it sets user_id =1

Using rails 3.1.3 w/ Devise

The controller:

```
def update_multiple

@user = current_user
for @workoutdate in params[:workout_workoutdates]
  is_new = false

  #this part works, user_id ends up equaling the current_user

  @workouts = Workout.where(:user_id => @user, 
                            :workoutdate => @workoutdate.to_time)
  if !@workouts.any?

    # when setting user_id to an integer it works
    # for example, workout = Workout.new(:user_id => 3), it works

    workout = Workout.new(:user_id => @user, 
                          :workoutdate => @workoutdate.to_time)
    is_new = true
  else
    workout = @workouts[0]
  end
  workout.save
end
```

And the resulting SQL from the terminal:

```
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "intervals" ("created_at", "interval_name", "updated_at", "workout_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 13 Dec 2011 03:24:28 UTC +00:00], ["interval_name", "INTERVAL"], ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Dec 2011 03:24:28 UTC +00:00], ["workout_id", nil]]

SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "workouts" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "workoutdate") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 13 Dec 2011 03:24:28 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Dec 2011 03:24:28 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1], ["workoutdate", Thu, 08 Dec 2011 08:00:00 UTC +00:00]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use devise differently. I think you're making it too difficult. With devise, you can reference a users objects (workouts) like this:

```
@workouts = current_user.workouts.find(...)
```

and then create a new one like so:

```
@workout = current_user.workout.build(...)
```

and so forth...

Comment: Thanks for the help; unfortunately, no dice.

I gave that a try but ended up with a "NoMethodError" ... undefined method `intervals' for nil:NilClass

intervals is a nested attribute under workouts

Comment: changed the "build" line to fit grammatically...

workout = current_user.workouts.build(...)  

worked!!!  Thanks!!!

Comment: +1 for this - my brain didn't recognized that current_user is an object :D